# The matrix determinant function is real-rooted or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Given two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size,

the univariate polynomial $p(t)=\det(A+tB)$ is real rooted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can a nonzero genuinely complex symmetric matrix have zero determinant. Yes
$$\pmatrix{1&i\\ i&-1}$$
does. So take
$$A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1},\qquad B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$$
and $t=i$.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, we must AT LEAST assume that $ A, B $ are real. We must also assume that $B\not= 0$, otherwise any complex $t$ is solution or there are no solutions. Even if we assume that $ B $ is invertible, it is not enough to get the result

Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}85&65\\65&24\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}-44&76\\76&51\end{pmatrix}$. I obtained these matrices at random from the first draw.

If you want to do math seriously, you will have to roll up your sleeves and do the preparatory work before asking this kind of question.

Try to think about this:

The result stands if $B$ is symmetric positive definite.